# Adjust height of specified table rows - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working with Bootstrap v3 and a simple table - however I need to adjust the height of specific rows in the table so they are smaller in height than the rest.
I've tried adding a specific tr class but that doesn't appear to have any effect.

Here's what I've got so far for the custom CSS:

```css
 <style type="text/css">
      tr.approvers {
        height:20px;
      }
    </style>
```

and here's the HTML table:

```html
<tr>
<td>Acme Widgets</td>
<td>1</td>
<td class="success">Approved</td>
<td>001</td>
</tr>
<tr class="approvers">
<td></td>
<td>John Smith</td>
<td class="success" colspan="2">20/10/2015 14:24:24</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work unless you wrap them inside `<table></table>`. `tr` not within `table` is considered invalid and the browser does not create the DOM tree for the rows. Thus the browser ignored all the `<tr>` `<td>` and your code was being executed as plain text.

```css
tr.approvers {
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Acme Widgets</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="success">Approved</td>
    <td>001</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="approvers">
    <td></td>
    <td>John Smith</td>
    <td class="success" colspan="2">20/10/2015 14:24:24</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```